# Python3 compiled App Decrease Size with zip?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, cx-freeze

I have compiled with success a rather big app ,but the size of the app is way too big(about 1 GB).I realized that almost the half (400MB) was taken from just 2 modules(PyQt5 and mpl_toolkits(basemap)).Of course the  one approach is to delete the side-services you dont need but i cant in my case as i use about all of these in my app.
Then i was thinking about ziping these modules but i don't know if this is safe or execute time viable.
So is there a suficient way to minimize the size of my app, and if the ZIP is the only answer is it viable to do this on a lib such PyQt5 witch is imported many times in my script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is entirely possible to do this; Python has always supported "zipapps", and as of 3.5, provides [a module, `zipapp`, to assist with creating them](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipapp.html).

The only concern is whether your dependencies run properly zipped; most do, but some take file-system layer dependencies that zipping (and eggs and the like) don't handle (the `setup.py` file for these would declare `zip_safe=False` to tell tools not to allow it). Packages with C extensions would have to assert `zip_safe=True`, as [the default analyzer assumes C extensions can't be safely zipped (though many can)](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#setting-the-zip-safe-flag).

It will slow down startup a bit (since it has to decompress the modules), but it shouldn't dramatically slow runtime, no matter how many times you import it; the first import is the only one that really matters, since subsequent imports just pull the cached copy of the module from an internal cache (`sys.modules`).